# How can I access a specific instance of a header or footer in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I can call `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to get a specific cell in order to modify that cell at any time--for instance, to update its label. I am speaking of the class instance method on `UICollectionView`, not the `UICollectionViewDataSource` method.

However, there does not appear to be a similar method for headers/footers. `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` will return unique instances of headers/footers, instead of giving an already allocated instance. Because of this, I cannot get a pointer to a header in order to update (say) a label. I am forced to reload the section and modify it in the body of the `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method.

Is there a proper way to get a pointer to a specific header/footer, without resorting to a custom object cache or tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't (it took until iOS 6 for there to be an equivalent call for a `UITableView`, `footer/headerViewForSection`).

If I had to guess why this isn't possible I'd say it's because in some layouts the `UICollectionView` will automatically re-layout and adjust the supplementary views, so adjusting view contents 'on the fly' could be problematic. However, assuming `UICollectionView` doesn't do anything funny like copying views you should probably be able to hold your supplementary views in a separate array and modify them that way - that said, no guarantees this won't introduce some odd or strange behaviour (same for your suggestion of using tags and going into the collection view hierarchy).

So the short answer is no - there isn't a method that supports this in the API. If you had a compelling use case it's probably worth filing a feature request through Apple's bug reporter though.

Comment: Thanks for the intelligent response. Going to leave this up for a bit to see if anyone else has any ideas, but I assume you're correct. I suppose I could always just use a UITableView if my layout allows.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to update your data model object in the data source, and then call `[myCollectionView reloadData]`. This will trigger your collection view to ask for the data again and update its subviews as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is to have the header views listen for an `NSNotification` that you broadcast, and then the ones that care can update themselves based on whatever criteria you have.

Or give them a tag and use `viewWithTag:`.